# I am having problem with tensorflow-gpu. Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.20GiB with freed_by_count=0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

System information

Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow):

1. OS: Windows 10 Home with 8GB ram, NVIDIA MX250 2GB graphic card.-
   TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Source "pip install tensorflow-gpu"
2. TensorFlow version :2.2.0
3. Python version: 3.6 CUDA/cuDNN version:
4. CUDA 10.2 and CUDNN: 8.0.3.33 i.e. for cuda 10.1 GPU model and
5. memory: NVIDIA MX250 with 2GB Graphic

---

**Problem**

My tensorflow-gpu was working fine. Once I have reinstall my anaconda and install tensorflow-gpu again after that
when every I try to train any model on tensorflow-gpu It always gives me this error:

---

Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
2020-09-24 21:35:23.361799: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.20GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-09-24 21:35:23.363348: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.02GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-09-24 21:35:23.627463: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.11GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.

---

**Simple Code**

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten,Conv2D,MaxPool2D,AvgPool2D,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_path="E:/AI-Application-Implementation/trained_model/Classification/Cifar-10/data/train"
test_path="E:/AI-Application-Implementation/trained_model/Classification/Cifar-10/data/test"

folders=glob("E:/All Data Set/CIFAR10/train/*")

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=0.5,
brightness_range=[0.2,0.5],
zoom_range=[0.1,0.8],
horizontal_flip=True,
validation_split=0.2,
rescale=1./255)

train=datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
target_size=(256,256),
# color_mode="grayscale",
shuffle=True,
class_mode='categorical',
subset='training')

test=datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
target_size=(256,256),
# color_mode="grayscale",
shuffle=True,
class_mode='categorical',
subset='validation')

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(256,256,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(AvgPool2D(pool_size=(6,6)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'])

history=model.fit(train,validation_data=test,epochs=5,steps_per_epoch=len(train),validation_steps=len(test))
```

Other info / logs Include any logs or source code that would be helpful to
**

---

**

> 2020-09-24 21:35:09.493907: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll Found 40000
> images belonging to 10 classes.
>
> 2020-09-24 21:35:09.493907: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:14.913210: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
>
> 2020-09-24 21:35:09.493907: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:14.913210: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.668676: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0
> with properties: pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce MX250
> computeCapability: 6.1 coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 3
> deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 44.76GiB/s 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.673588: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.729057: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.750802: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.756718: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.777083: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.781830: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.795484: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.795889: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0 2020-09-24 21:35:15.797938: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to
> use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:
> AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the
> appropriate compiler flags. 2020-09-24 21:35:15.809116: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service
> 0x29073047360 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee
> that XLA will be used). Devices: 2020-09-24 21:35:15.810096: I
> tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176] StreamExecutor device
> (0): Host, Default Version 2020-09-24 21:35:15.811012: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0
> with properties: pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0 name: GeForce MX250
> computeCapability: 6.1 coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 3
> deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 44.76GiB/s 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.812247: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.812911: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.813512: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.814104: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.814716: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.815307: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.815903: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48]
> Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll 2020-09-24
> 21:35:15.816520: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible
> gpu devices: 0 Found 10000 images belonging to 10 classes. Model:
> "sequential"

Comment: If any one can help me or have any suggestions then please comment or contact me on:                                GitHub: https://github.com/gauravrajwada
Medium: https://medium.com/@GauravRajwada
LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/gaurav-singh-b90369191/
Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/gauravrajwada/
Twitter: https://twitter.com/GauravRajwada s

Comment: It is not an error: "The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available."

Comment: And this is not a forum, there is no need to leave personal information, nobody is going to contact you through other means.

Comment: Deep learning applications usually desire large GPU memory (>= 8 GB). 2 GB of GPU memory is kind of small. Consider a hardware upgrade.

Comment: But when I use it before it work fine for me. Once I reinstall anaconda after that it create problem.